# Get module name and controller name of the activated route

Tags: angular

Using Angular 13, given a route, how can I get module name and controller name of the current activated route or url?

```
     constructor(
        private readonly router: Router,
        private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
      }

     ngOnInit(): void {
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular allows us to pass data to the route static or dynamic using the data property.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent, data :{ id: module.id, name:"ControllerName or Wherever Value"}},
];
```

You can read the information using the ActivatedRoute

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 

     constructor(private activatedroute:ActivatedRoute) {
     }
 
     ngOnInit() {
          this.activatedroute.data.subscribe(data => {
               console.log(data);
           })
     }
}
```

The official Angular documentation have great information about how to use.
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute